# Typekit font not loading in webkit browsers

Tags: css, webkit, webfonts, typekit

I'm using two fonts from typekit:

```
font-family:"proxima-nova", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; - WORKS OK
```

and

```
font-family:"garamond-premier-pro", Georgia, serif; - DOESN'T DISPLAY
```

While Proxima Nova loads ok - **Garamond Premier Pro fails to load** - but **only in Chrome and Safari**. Firefox and IE display the font ok. The css rule is ok - it even shows up in web inspector - I get no errors in console - typekit script is loaded - still the font won't display - it falls back to georgia.

I tried different solutions I found around (moving typekit script on top of header, disable `text-shadow`, remove `-webkit` prefixed rules from css) - nothing helps.

Is this problem font related? I read that webkit browsers have problems with opentype.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Garamond Premier Pro is a [commercial product](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1737) of Adobe. If you have purchased a license that allows web font usage, contact the vendor if the product does not work. Otherwise, don’t try to use it as a web font.

Comment: Shouldn't fonts served by typekit comply to licences by default? Isn't this the point of their service - to provide licensed fonts for web at lower price?

Comment: If you purchased a licence from Typekit, contact Typekit, but make sure you describe the problem well (a self-contained document that demonstrates the issue plus a list of browsers tested, with version numbers and platforms). Check first http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/807568-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Got it solved - first I removed all font declarations from css and started adding them back. Still wouldn't work. Then I specified the font by applying all possible font propertis (from size to weight) - once I added `font-style:italic` Garamond finally started working in Chrome - very dumb fix.